# Returning Zipcode from Geolocation in Meteor

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, meteor, geolocation

```
<template name="home">
 <a href="#" id="showMyLocation">Where Am I</a>
 <div id="location">Postal Address</div>
 <div id="zipcode">Zip Code</div>
</template>
```

I'm trying to retrieve user's current address and zipcode using Geolocation in Meteor. Any help or advice will be appreciated.

this is the Javascript

```
Meteor.startup(function() {  
GoogleMaps.load(); 
});

Template.home.events({
'click #showMyLocation': function(event){ 
  event.preventDefault();
   $(this).html('Determining address...');
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function (position){
       var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
       var latLng   = new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude, 
       position.coords.longitude);
        geocoder.geocode({
         'latLng': latLng}, 
           function (results, status){
            for (var i = 0; i < results[0].address_components.length; i++) {
             var address = results[0].address_components[i];
              if (address.types[0] == "postal_code"){
                $('#zipcode').html(address.long_name);
                $('#location').html(results[0].formatted_address);
                $('#showMyLocation').hide();
                }
            }
        });
    });
    return false;
}
});
```

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do is called [Reverse Geocoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_geocoding). Heres how you can do it with Google maps Javascript API https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/geocoding-reverse

You can also use [Geonames API](http://www.geonames.org/maps/osm-reverse-geocoder.html) to do that.